# Equivalent of "description" for a C++ class in Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++, lldb

I want to be able to debug objective-c++ code which contains instances of a c++ class quickly.

With objective-c classes, I can simply implement `description` to return a human readable string, and then when I `po var` in lldb I immediately know anything I need to know about the instance.

Is there any way I can achieve this for c++ classes used from objective-c++ code as well?

Comment: You'd have to do whatever you'd do for a C++ class that was **not** being used in Objective-C++.

Comment: I understand I can add a `description()` method and call it from lldb. I wonder if I can quickly see it in Xcode's (AppCode's) debugger variables overview  without having to explicitly call any methods, like I can for objective-c classes that implement `- description`.

Comment: I think for c++ you'd need to use lldb extensions implemented in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in lldb is to add a "summary formatter" for the C++ class.  This web page gives a pretty good intro to how to do this:

http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

Look for the section on "Type Summaries".

If the class's ivar values directly contain all you want to see about the class, then you can cons up a summary string that will present the ivar values and any markup text you think desirable without having to use the LLDB Python API's to take apart the class.  If you need to do more work to produce your summary, you will have to use the Python API's as trojanfoe suggests.

For instance, if you wrote a "description" method for your C++ class, you could use LLDB's Python API's to call that method and return the string as the summary.  But if possible, it is preferable to produce the summary from static knowledge of the class, since running code in the debugger is generally slower than inspecting memory.

There is also information on how to use the LLDB Python interface to produce summaries on the same page.

The Type Summaries you write can be added in your .lldbinit file, and the summary values will show up when you print an instance of the class in lldb, and also in the summary column in the Locals view in Xcode.

Note, you can do this for any type, C, C++ or ObjC.  Many of the C++ STL classes and the more common Foundation classes have built-in summaries that use the same mechanism.  That, and not the description method, is how lldb produces the one-line summaries you see in Xcode.

Comment: Of course, this means that you still have to do your own work for ivars in an ObjC object that are C++ instances, because using %@ in a format string only works for ObjC objects, and isn't equivalent to po in LLDB. E.g. you could add a GetDebugDescription() member function to the C++ object and then do NSLog(@"foo { bar = %@, cppBar = %s }", self->bar, self->cppBar.GetDebugDescription().c_str() ); or whatever.

Comment: The interesting part here is that "po" is a language-defined behavior. Namely it means "evaluate my expression, then use some language-sanctioned mechanism to present a description of it". It just so happens that ObjC has defined such a mechanism (-description). OTOH, there is no such obvious and generally-agreed-upon thing in the C++ universe. You could implement ostream operator << on your object, or have a toString() method, or have a dump() method, all of which seem to happen in real code. Which is also why you don't get an equivalent of %@ for C++ - how would that work?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Didn't know about `.lldbinit`. I wonder if there's something I can do in code though - so it would be a class specific settings and not a home-dir specific setting.